# How to handle "No products found." with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, exception, cypress

I am trying to automate with Cypress a Calculator that is counting the discount in combination of couple products.

All the product numbers are coming randomly from json file, saved in fixtures.
Right now I have an issue, because some of the products are not available and it appears the message in the calculator : "No products found."

I don't want my test to fail. I was wondering which approach is better:

1. To confirm if any of those products populated before trying to add it to the product list

or

2. To say that if the product is missing : clear the search field and choose another one and repeat until you find available product.

Attached is the way how I call the product, wait 3 sec to appear, click on it and clear the search field.
Verify if the $1000 discount is there, end the test and take screenshoot.

I would really appreciate if you could help me here.

Thank you!

cy.get('#search').type(this.randomAdditionalProducts).type('{shift}').type('{shift}')
cy.wait(3000)
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .response-card-body > .product-price-container > .add-product-button > .response-model-action').click()
cy.get('#search').clear()

cy.get('body.page.basicpage div.responsivegrid.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--12:nth-child(4) div.aem-Grid.aem-Grid--12.aem-Grid--default--12 div.raw-html.baseComponent.aem-GridColumn.aem-GridColumn--default--12:nth-child(3) div.calculator-app-container.ng-scope:nth-child(2) div.container.calculator-container:nth-child(1) div.row.calculator-row div.calculator-row-left div.col-md-4.product-list-container div.product-list-top-container div.mobile-stick-bottom p.list-info:nth-child(2) > span.lead.ng-binding').contains('$1,000').end()
cy.screenshot()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4iBg.png)

Comment: Please add your code in the question and not image.

Comment: My opinion: I think the problem is that randomness. It makes the test unpredictable.
It can be done this way, but then we would ensure that each product number ( id?) in the fixture is from an available product (is it possible?). And test the expected behavior.
The «No products found» could be tested in another test, with another fixture with known «not available» products, so we expect to get such «No products found» message and we test it appears.

Note: some selectors in that code are pretty lenghty, maybe they could be replaced adding a `data-testid` in the elements, if possible.